# How to implement with SQL table or with a stored procedure a DataGridView with combobox (ComboBox implement with stored procedure)

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, combobox

I need to have a `DataGridView` with a combobox.

I need to implement the `DataGridView` with a stored procedure, and the combobox needs to replace column in the stored procedure (`DataGridView`) which contains `ID`

So combobox need to have value "ID" and display "Name"

But how to to implement correctly the `DataGridView`? And I need that combobox show value for result of the stored procedure?

Comment: so what you tried till now?

Comment: I know how to bind a datagriedView and how to implement a combobox with a stored procedure but I need to join this 2 things ... I need to have an example

Answer (score 0):

As you say that you know how to bind datagridview and how to implement a combobox with a stored procedure, however its very hard to understand what you actually want and what you describe in your question.

Follow this pseudo code to target what you want to achieve:

- Step 1: `BindComboxBox()` call SQL query or stored procedure to get data from database
- Step 2: Create `SelectedIndexChanged event` for combobox
- Step 3: in this `SelectedIndexChanged event`, get the `ComboBox1.SelectedItem`(ID in your case) and call the  function `BindGrid(int ID)` and pass `ComboBox1.SelectedItem` as input parameter
- Step 4: create a function `BindGrid(int ID)`, this function gets the data from database using a stored procedure, which has an input parameter `ID`. Then bind your grid.